# Backups for my site, file and/or SQL

Tags: mysql, file, backup

I need to find a good backup solution for the site I have hosted with HostGator.  HostGator only backs up sites with less than X number of files.  Unfortunately I've exceeded that limit and they aren't backing up my site any more.

This means that right now i have no database backups.  I do have backups of all the files on my computer, which I'm good with.  But I need to find a solution that backs up my databases **with no manual maintenance**.  HostGator doesn't offer additional backup services.

My site has cPanel access.

Any suggestions for solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysqldump is a simple and reliable way to do backups.
Explore the documentation: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

If you want to copy your dumps on another server, you can write a bash script that copies dumps over ssh.
Here are some links that may help you:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-copy-mysql-database-remote-server.html

http://christiank.org/wp/2010/12/pipe-a-gzipped-mysql-dump-over-ssh/

Comment: I don't exactly have another server I can copy them to